# Is it possible to use NewSingleHostReverseProxy in a GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to build a simple proxy that runs on GAE and simply redirects all calls to an internal server I have open only to the GAE ip address.

I have some local code making use of the `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` that is working.  I'm not sure how to make it work on GAE though since there is no `main()` function

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{Scheme: "http", Host: "mydomian.com:3000"})
    error := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE applications (servlets) work by answering specific requests made to the web server. In this case, you should embed the whole proxy in your methods processing get and post requests. That's because GAE is thought to run code that handles a request and exits. In short, you'd need to create a proxy outside GAE, either in Google Compute Engine, either in another server.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion.  I'll just stub out all of the API calls in the GAE web server and make the individual calls to my server
Thanks